# Java strange output: [Ljava.lang.String;@1aa8c488 (string.split("\\s"))

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a very simple parser splitting string:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Parser {

public static void main(String args[]){

    String newLog = new String();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/John/IdeaProjects/tomcatParser/src/log.log"));
        try {
            while ((newLog = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(newLog.split("\\s"));
                //System.out.println(newLog.split(" "));
                break;
            }
            //reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I've got absolutely simple code, but as the result i see :

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1aa8c488
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, you just print a String array to `System.out`. What is your question and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to print an array object: this will not print the array members, but the array reference.

One solution: surround with `Arrays.asList()`, ie:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(newLog.split("\\s")));
```

(better solution: use `Arrays.toString()` as suggested by the other answers. You learn something new every day.)

Comment: And one more question - how could i convert each separate part of lis to string?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: So, I need an array which contains parts of string, which we just separated.

Comment: Then use `final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(newLog.split("\\s"));`, it will contain all strings. But you could as well cycle through the array.

Answer (score 3):

That's what you get when you try to print an array directly. It uses the `toString` method of the `Object` class which prints out the name of the class, the at-sign character and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. You get the "identity" of the array rather than a textual representation of its contents.

Instead, use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newLog.split("\\s")));
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` works with string. When you are passing object that is not string its method `toString()` is called automatically and you see the result of this call.

You are calling `System.out.println` with array argument and this is how `toString()` of arrays work. To see better output use

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newLog.split("\\s")))`

Answer (score 1):

Method `String.split(String regEx)` return array of strings (`String[]`).

When you try to `System.out.println` any `Object` in Java it calls this object `toString()` method. `toString()` method for array returns exectly is what you see.

Use  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newLog.split("\\s")));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
while ((newLog = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(newLog.split("\\s"));
    //System.out.println(newLog.split(" "));
    break;
}
```

your code should be:

```
while ((newLog = reader.readLine()) != null){
  String [] columns = newLog.split("\\s"); 
  for (String result : columns) {
    System.out.print(result);
  }
  break;
}
```